# What to restart the thread if failed

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have a code where I used blocking queue to make pub/sub async if my thread failed it will not consume anything how can I solve it.

```java
@Service
public abstract class AsyncPublisher<T> extends GeneralPublisher<T> {

    private final BlockingQueue<T> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    public AsyncPublisher() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    T t = blockingQueue.take();
                    super.publish(t);
                } catch (Throwable er) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error in AsyncPublisher in Thread", er);
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void publish(T t) {
        try {
            blockingQueue.put(t);
        } catch (Exception er) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in AsyncPublisher during publishing", er);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a thread pool instead.

Comment: Never catch `Throwable`, regardless of what your problem is. What do you mean "the thread fails". This sort of loop should not allow your thread to fail. Can you give an example of when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless the comments, what you need to do to "fix" your problem is to change the structure of your class. 
Instead of initializing the thread in the constructor ( thus autostart ). You can create some methods like `start`, `stop`, `isRunning` and handle your thread with those.

Keep a reference to your thread to "monitor" it. Also from your `@Service` i believe you use Spring. Spring has a Lifecycle ( https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html ) and smartlifecycle (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) which you can use to insert your class in the context and let spring monitor it if its running or not and restart it.

This approach is common ( apart Spring and other project that use it is Project-Reactor https://projectreactor.io/ which returns an item called `Displosable` with a function `isDisplosed` to keep track of the `stream` you created. `Stream` is Reactor-Specific reference here. )